# Group By with Multiple Unique Constraints Condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to fetch data from below mentioned table Sizes where data will be unique by Code,ArtId and Size OR unique By Code,ArtId and SizeIndex (i.e There are two unique constraints).How I can get unique records in single select statement using group by .

```
ArtId | SizeIndex       | Size           | Description          |   Code
001   | 000000000001111 | X              | TEST                 |   01
002   | 000000000001111 | XL             | NULL                 |   02
003   | 000000000001111 | L              | NULL                 |   03
004   | 000000000009999 | SL             | TEST2                |   04
005   | 000000000009999 | ML             | LIGHT                |   05
006   | 000000000009999 | M              | Filter element,Air   |   06
```

Your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean with "unique records"? Each record is unique if you have least one unique constraint.

Comment: Not clear at all what is desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ART_ID,SIZEiNDEX,SIZE, Description ,CODE FROM 
(SELECT ART_ID,SIZEiNDEX,SIZE, Description ,CODE
FROM TABLE GROUP BY CODE,ARTID,SIZE

UNION

SELECT ART_ID,SIZEiNDEX,SIZE, Description ,CODE
FROMM TABLE GROUP BY CODE,ARTID,SIZEINDEX)A
```